# Changing the language while loading the application is not flipping the UI in arabic

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using Apple's default way to support arabic in my application. From iOS 9, UIKit controls will be automatically flipped if the language is set while loading the application. So on launching the application in main.m I am adding following code

```
NSString *userPreferredLanguage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserPreferedAppLanguage"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:userPreferredLanguage, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

However localization is not happening fully and views are not flipped, Next time when I launch the app, views are flipped and full localization takes place. I am using AFNetworking and few other libraries which does swizzling, I think this is causing the issue. Anyone has faced the similar issue?

Comment: go through the link may it will help you - https://medium.com/@dark_torch/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4

Comment: @AbdulKarim issue is due to the conflict with other libraries, localization works perfectly fine without these libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved my following code from main.m to the load method in AppDelegate and it worked!!

```
NSString *userPreferredLanguage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserPreferedAppLanguage"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:userPreferredLanguage, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

The issue was in one of the frameworks I had in my project. Their internal implementation might have had these loading of NSBundle in load method, due to which my code in main.m had no effect, because load method is called before main function.